# Twilio unable to embed webhook into studio flow and have it send me message

Tags: python, twilio

I wrote a simple script to send a text to a user when the user sends a text first. When I link the phone number directly to webhook, it all works fine; but when I embed the webhook as a http request in studio flow, the function gets ran (I had debugging print statements that got ran) but the messages doesn't get sent to the user. Can anyone tell me why that is?

For reference, here is my code

```html
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
 
from tags import get_relevant_tags

app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message("a")
    return str(resp)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use an HTTP request as part of a Twilio Studio flow, the response is received by the flow itself, rather than being used to control the messages sent to the user.

If you don't need any outside input from whatever server is running that code, then I recommend replacing the HTTP request with a send message widget from Studio.

If you are doing some outside processing on your server that you need as part of the flow then I recommend you return the result as JSON with the message you want to send embedded. Something like:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

@app.route('/sms', methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    message = get_awesome_message()
    return jsonify(message=message)
```

Then, within the Studio flow, once that request returns successfully, further widgets, includng a send message widget, can then use the results by calling on `widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.parsed`. Check out further detail on [using the HTTP request widget in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#http-request).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and it works now. However, I now have a different issue when I am using Tensorflow with Twilio. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407854/unable-to-send-message-back-to-twilio-after-running-tensorflow  Do you think the JSON solution would help with this as well?

Comment: I'll take a look at your other question. If this answer helped, then please do mark it as correct so that others will be able to see it helped too. Thanks!