# Unable to send message back to Twilio after running Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, twilio

I am making a chatbot that sends an HTTP request through ngrok to a local python file which runs a image recognition script using Tensorflow. The script will then return a string back to Twilio that will be sent back to the user.

The file runs until the end without error and all the debugging print statements printed the right things in my terminal. However, Twilio says I have an error 81014 and the string I returned isn't received my Twilio.

Some trial and error showed me that the following line is causing the error (it came from the label_image.py file in tensorflow)

```html
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
      input_operation.outputs[0]: t
  })
```

I also noticed that many lines that I did not print is being printed in my terminal. I am not sure if there is a correlation in that. Here are some of the lines:

```html
Optimizing fused batch norm node name: "import/module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/FusedBatchNorm"
op: "FusedBatchNorm"
input: "import/module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/Conv2D"
input: "import/module_apply_default/InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/Const"
input: "import/module/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/beta"
input: "import/module/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_mean"
input: "import/module/InceptionV3/Mixed_6d/Branch_3/Conv2d_0b_1x1/BatchNorm/moving_variance"
device: "/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "data_format"
  value {
    s: "NHWC"
  }
}
attr {
  key: "epsilon"
  value {
    f: 0.001
  }
}
attr {
  key: "is_training"
  value {
    b: false
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why Twilio is failing?

Comment: You say that your operation runs all the way to the end without error, but then say that you found a part of your code that was causing an error, so I'm confused. What are you returning as the result of the HTTP request? How long does it take for the request to run?

Comment: The script runs without error. But the process of returning a value back to Twilio caused Twilio to give an error. I am only returning a string, for debugging purposes, I even tried to return just "a" which still caused an error. I am not sure if Tensorflow is returning something of its own though. It takes a max of 10 seconds to run which is normal for Tensorflow.

Comment: Ok, the HTTP request widget in Studio has a time out of 5 seconds, so if your request takes 10 seconds it will time out. I would look into reducing the time your application takes to return a result. You also need to respond with valid JSON, so if you're just retuning the character "a" then that will not work either. You can see more about [making HTTP requests with Studio in the widget documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library#http-request).